# Is there a faster way to export data from Dask DataFrame to CSV?

Tags: python, csv, dask

I am reading CSV file (10 GB) using Dask. Then after performing some operations, I am Exporting file in CSV format using `to_csv`. But problem is that exporting this file is taking around *27 Minutes* (According to ProgressBar Diagnostics).

CSV file includes 350 columns with one column of timestamp and other column's datatype are set to `float64`.

- Machine Specs:

  - Intel i7-4610M @ 3.00 GHz
  - 8 GB DDR3 RAM
  - 500 GB SSD
  - Windows 10 Pro

I have tried exporting in separate files like `to_csv('filename-*.csv')` and also have tried without including `.csv`. So, Dask exports file with extension of `.part`. But doing this also takes same time as mentioned above.

I think this should not be an issue with I/O operations as I am using SSD. But I am not sure about that.

Here is my code (simplified):

```py
df = dd.read_csv('path\\to\\csv')
# Doing some operations using df.loc
df.to_csv('export.csv', single_file=True)
```

I am using Dask v2.6.0.

Expected output --> complete this process in less time without changing specs of machine.

Is there anyway, I can export this file in less time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default dask dataframe uses the multi-threaded scheduler.  This is optimal for most pandas operations, but `read_csv` partially holds onto the GIL, so you might want to try using the multi-processing or dask.distributed schedulers.

See more information about that here: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/scheduling.html

If you can, I also recommend using a more efficient file format, like Parquet

https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-best-practices.html#store-data-in-apache-parquet-format

Comment: Using Parquet is defiantly an improvement as it's taking now only around 3 Minutes. Using schedulers are cherry on top.  More on `to_parquet` [Doc for to_parquet](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.to_parquet)